# What could cause a POST request to be sent as a GET request in C# / ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have two ASP.NET Core 7 applications deployed on Azure app service. For certain requests, `service1` needs to make a `POST` request on a private vnet to `service2`. This works fine in our staging environment. However, in our production environment the `POST` is converted to a `GET` for some reason, causing the request to fail.

What could be some reason for .NET Core to convert an outgoing `POST` request to a `GET`?

Context - adding extra logging to Refit:

```cs
services
    .AddRefitClient<IService2Api>(
        (sp) =>
            new RefitSettings
            {
                CollectionFormat = CollectionFormat.Multi,
                HttpMessageHandlerFactory = () =>
                    new LoggingHandler(
                        sp.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()
                            .CreateLogger<LoggingHandler>(),
                        new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true }
                    )
            }
    )
    .ConfigureHttpClient(
        // ...
```

`LoggingHandler`:

```cs
private class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoggingHandler> logger;

    public LoggingHandler(ILogger<LoggingHandler> logger, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    protected override HttpResponseMessage Send(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        logger.LogDebug("Before [{Method}] to {Url}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);
        var response = base.Send(request, cancellationToken);
        logger.LogDebug("After [{Method}] to {Url}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);
        return response;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        logger.LogDebug("Before [{Method}] to {Url}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        logger.LogDebug("After [{Method}] to {Url}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
2023-11-24 23:34:11.315 +00:00 [Information] System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Refit.Implementation.Generated+IService2Api, Common, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.ClientHandler: Sending HTTP request POST http://service2.azurewebsites.net/my/endpoint/
2023-11-24 23:34:11.315 +00:00 [Trace] System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Refit.Implementation.Generated+IService2Api, Common, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.ClientHandler: Request Headers:
Authorization: Bearer [Redacted]
User-Agent: Service1, (Service1/1.0.1.0)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

2023-11-24 23:34:11.315 +00:00 [Debug] LoggingHandler: Before [POST] to http://service2.azurewebsites.net/my/endpoint/
2023-11-24 23:34:11.400 +00:00 [Debug] LoggingHandler: After [GET] to https://service2.azurewebsites.net/my/endpoint/
2023-11-24 23:34:11.401 +00:00 [Information] System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Refit.Implementation.Generated+IService2Api, Common, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.ClientHandler: Received HTTP response headers after 85.2956ms - 405
2023-11-24 23:34:11.401 +00:00 [Trace] System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Refit.Implementation.Generated+IService2Api, Common, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.ClientHandler: Response Headers:
Date: Fri, 24 Nov 2023 23:34:11 GMT
Set-Cookie: [Redacted]
Content-Length: 0
Allow: POST
```

See also:

- https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/1620

Comment: Are you sure there's data to POST (not `Content-Length: 0`)?

Comment: Yes, I'm posting an array of strings in the body. Still, that shouldn't affect the verb though, right?

Comment: Well, a post with content-length 0 is not a legal post, which is why you should make sure there are content.

Comment: Hm, there really should be but I'll make sure to double check. Thanks for the tip @PoulBak

Comment: You don't have anything in the middle like nginx do you? I had a server that was converting POST to GET because a replacement server was configured by default to redirect all `domain.tld` to `www.domain.tld` while the old server was originally `www.domain.tld` to `domain.tld`. When I removed the redirect and allowed either format, I stopped getting the POST changed to GET by nginx.

Comment: @B.O.B.: Yes, a redirect could also explain it.

Comment: I believe the services are hosted in IIS. My first thought was indeed something to do with redirects - but I'm not aware of any rules stating that a redirect should cause the verb to change. Given that we only get this behavior in prod and not stage I also decided to downpriorize. However, hearing that someone else has had a similar problem makes a redirect (from http to https perhaps? ) seem more likely again.

Comment: "*I'm not aware of any rules stating that a redirect should cause the verb to change*". A status code of 301 or 302 (which are the most used) will ALWAYS result in a get request! Only 307 and 308 keep the verb.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.3

Comment: This is 100% an environmental issue, nothing to do with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the reference PoulBak - that's certainly good to know! Also, thank you @B.O.B. I'm almost certain now that the issue is one of redirecting from http to https. I still need to verify on Monday but you have both been a great help!

Comment: Minor correction, if I'm reading the RFC correctly. status 301 and 302 are not supposed to change the verb. However, many implementations erroneously do so: *If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user [...] Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents will erroneously change it into a GET request.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ConfigureHttpClient`, try disabling redirects by setting `AllowAutoRedirect = false` in your `HttpClientHandler` (example for Refit):

```cs
services
    .AddRefitClient<T>(
        (sp) =>
            new()
            {
                HttpMessageHandlerFactory = () =>
                    new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = false }
            }
    )
```

Then log the response status and headers.

I think you have a 301/302 redirect in the mix somehow and the default behaviour of the http client is to automatically follow it.

Maybe you've configured your base URL in one environment to start with `http://` and the server is configured to redirect to `https://`?

Comment: I'll verify on Monday but I have a good feeling about this one being about a http to https redirect now. Thank you!

Comment: Confirmed. Service 1 would receive a 301 redirect which caused the `POST` to be converted to a `GET`. Not sure why this did not happen in stage as well but no matter - updating our URLs to use HTTPS and setting `AllowAutoRedirect` to false solved the issue.